Want to export 3d model from unity which is supportable with SketchUp
I am developing a cabinet design center and I am finding a way to export the 3d model that I design inside unity. All of the meshes and materials that need to be exported are in one single parent(see image). Specifically I want to export a 3d file that is compatible with SketchUp (.fbx is not supportable). Would you have any idea how to do this?
I have tried with exporting the .obj file but I get only geometry in exported file not materials in color here is the script of that approch.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class OBJExporter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool onlySelectedObjects = false;
    public bool applyPosition = true;
    public bool applyRotation = true;
    public bool applyScale = true;
    public bool generateMaterials = true;
    public bool exportTextures = true;
    public bool splitObjects = true;
    public bool autoMarkTexReadable = false;
    public bool objNameAddIdNum = false;
    string exportPath = "";
    private string lastExportFolder;
    private string versionString = "v2.0";
    public Transform targetObject;


    string MaterialToString(Material m)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("newmtl " + m.name);

        // Add properties for URP Lit material
        // Base color
        if (m.HasProperty("_BaseColor"))
        {
            Color baseColor = m.GetColor("_BaseColor");
            //Debug.Log(ColorToHex(baseColor));
            sb.AppendLine("Kd " + baseColor.r.ToString() + " " + baseColor.g.ToString() + " " + baseColor.b.ToString());
            if (baseColor.a < 1.0f)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Tr " + (1f - baseColor.a).ToString());
                sb.AppendLine("d " + baseColor.a.ToString());
            }
        }

        sb.AppendLine("illum 2");
        return sb.ToString();
    }   

    string TryExportTexture(string propertyName, Material m)
    {
        if (m.HasProperty(propertyName))
        {
            Texture t = m.GetTexture(propertyName);
        }

        return "false";
    }

    Vector3 MultiplyVec3s(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return new Vector3(v1.x * v2.x, v1.y * v2.y, v1.z * v2.z);
    }

    Vector3 RotateAroundPoint(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Quaternion angle)
    {
        return angle * (point - pivot) + pivot;
    }

    private string ConstructOBJString(int index)
    {
        string idxString = index.ToString();
        return idxString + "/" + idxString + "/" + idxString;
    }

    void Export()
    {
        exportPath = Application.dataPath + "/testobj.obj";
        //init stuff
        Dictionary<string, bool> materialCache = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        var exportFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(exportPath);
        lastExportFolder = exportFileInfo.Directory.FullName;
        string baseFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(exportPath);
        //get list of required export things
        MeshFilter[] sceneMeshes;
        if (onlySelectedObjects)
        {
            List<MeshFilter> tempMFList = GetAllMeshFiltersInHierarchy(targetObject);
            sceneMeshes = tempMFList.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            sceneMeshes = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter[];
        }

        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            foreach (MeshFilter mf in sceneMeshes)
            {
                MeshRenderer mr = mf.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            }
        }

        //work on export
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbMaterials = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("# Export of " + Application.loadedLevelName);
        sb.AppendLine("# from Aaro4130 OBJ Exporter " + versionString);
        if (generateMaterials)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("mtllib " + baseFileName + ".mtl");
        }

        float maxExportProgress = (float)(sceneMeshes.Length + 1);
        int lastIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sceneMeshes.Length; i++)
        {
            string meshName = sceneMeshes[i].gameObject.name;
            float progress = (float)(i + 1) / maxExportProgress;
            MeshFilter mf = sceneMeshes[i];
            MeshRenderer mr = sceneMeshes[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            if (splitObjects)
            {
                string exportName = meshName;
                if (objNameAddIdNum)
                {
                    exportName += "_" + i;
                }

                sb.AppendLine("g " + exportName);
            }

            if (mr != null && generateMaterials)
            {
                Material[] mats = mr.sharedMaterials;
                for (int j = 0; j < mats.Length; j++)
                {
                    Material m = mats[j];
                    if (!materialCache.ContainsKey(m.name))
                    {
                        materialCache[m.name] = true;
                        sbMaterials.Append(MaterialToString(m));
                        sbMaterials.AppendLine();
                    }
                }
            }

            //export the meshhh :3
            Mesh msh = mf.sharedMesh;
            int faceOrder = (int)Mathf.Clamp((mf.gameObject.transform.lossyScale.x * mf.gameObject.transform.lossyScale.z), -1, 1);
            //export vector data (FUN :D)!
            foreach (Vector3 vx in msh.vertices)
            {
                Vector3 v = vx;
                if (applyScale)
                {
                    v = MultiplyVec3s(v, mf.gameObject.transform.lossyScale);
                }

                if (applyRotation)
                {
                    v = RotateAroundPoint(v, Vector3.zero, mf.gameObject.transform.rotation);
                }

                if (applyPosition)
                {
                    v += mf.gameObject.transform.position;
                }

                v.x *= -1;
                sb.AppendLine("v " + v.x + " " + v.y + " " + v.z);
            }

            foreach (Vector3 vx in msh.normals)
            {
                Vector3 v = vx;
                if (applyScale)
                {
                    v = MultiplyVec3s(v, mf.gameObject.transform.lossyScale.normalized);
                }

                if (applyRotation)
                {
                    v = RotateAroundPoint(v, Vector3.zero, mf.gameObject.transform.rotation);
                }

                v.x *= -1;
                sb.AppendLine("vn " + v.x + " " + v.y + " " + v.z);
            }

            foreach (Vector2 v in msh.uv)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("vt " + v.x + " " + v.y);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < msh.subMeshCount; j++)
            {
                if (mr != null && j < mr.sharedMaterials.Length)
                {
                    string matName = mr.sharedMaterials[j].name;
                    sb.AppendLine("usemtl " + matName);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("usemtl " + meshName + "_sm" + j);
                }

                int[] tris = msh.GetTriangles(j);
                for (int t = 0; t < tris.Length; t += 3)
                {
                    int idx2 = tris[t] + 1 + lastIndex;
                    int idx1 = tris[t + 1] + 1 + lastIndex;
                    int idx0 = tris[t + 2] + 1 + lastIndex;
                    if (faceOrder < 0)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("f " + ConstructOBJString(idx2) + " " + ConstructOBJString(idx1) + " " + ConstructOBJString(idx0));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("f " + ConstructOBJString(idx0) + " " + ConstructOBJString(idx1) + " " + ConstructOBJString(idx2));
                    }
                }
            }

            lastIndex += msh.vertices.Length;
        }

        //write to disk
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(exportPath, sb.ToString());
        if (generateMaterials)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(exportFileInfo.Directory.FullName + "\\" + baseFileName + ".mtl", sbMaterials.ToString());
        }
    }


    public List<MeshFilter> GetAllMeshFiltersInHierarchy(Transform parent)
    {
        List<MeshFilter> meshFilters = new List<MeshFilter>();
        FindMeshFilters(parent, meshFilters);
        return meshFilters;
    }

    private void FindMeshFilters(Transform parent, List<MeshFilter> meshFilters)
    {
        MeshFilter meshFilter = parent.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        if (meshFilter != null && meshFilter.gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            meshFilters.Add(meshFilter);
        }

        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            FindMeshFilters(child, meshFilters);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Export();
        }
    }

    string ColorToHex(Color color)
    {
        Color32 color32 = color;
        return string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", color32.r, color32.g, color32.b);
    }
}


This is not a single question
To do that you have to implement a 3d converter because you are mixing things like a unity material with an obj mesh and textures.
You should create your material and every element according to the file format you want to export and with their restrictions:
File structure
Vertex data
o       geometric vertices (v)
o       texture vertices (vt)
o       vertex normals (vn)
o       parameter space vertices (vp)
Free-form curve/surface attributes
o       rational or non-rational forms of curve or surface type:
basis matrix, Bezier, B-spline, Cardinal, Taylor (cstype)
o       degree (deg)
o       basis matrix (bmat)
o       step size (step)
Elements
o       point (p)
o       line (l)
o       face (f)
o       curve (curv)
o       2D curve (curv2)
o       surface (surf)
Free-form curve/surface body statements
o       parameter values (parm)
o       outer trimming loop (trim)
o       inner trimming loop (hole)
o       special curve (scrv)
o       special point (sp)
o       end statement (end)
Connectivity between free-form surfaces
o       connect (con)
Grouping
o       group name (g)
o       smoothing group (s)
o       merging group (mg)
o       object name (o)
Display/render attributes
o       bevel interpolation (bevel)
o       color interpolation (c_interp)
o       dissolve interpolation (d_interp)
o       level of detail (lod)
o       material name (usemtl)
o       material library (mtllib)
o       shadow casting (shadow_obj)
o       ray tracing (trace_obj)
o       curve approximation technique (ctech)
o       surface approximation technique (stech)
